# Limit characters or letters in category product name on opencart 2.0

Tags: css, opencart2.x

In opencart 2.0 how to set the limit characters or letters on product name on category page ?
Any one please answer this

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, You want to restrict Product name in one line instead or two or more line. So, You can use below css & easily product name convert in one line (exp.- my product name....)

```
.product-thumb h4{
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```